# Cohomology classes fixed by algebraic automorphism subgroups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, hodge-theory, algebraic-cycles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex variety and $t\in H^{2p}(X,\mathbf{Q})(p)$ a rational cohomology class.

Assume that there exist
$$t_1,\ldots,t_N\in H^{2*}(X,\mathbf{Q})(*)$$
algebraic classes (i.e. in the image of the cycle map $cl : A^*(X)\to H^{2*}(X,\mathbf{Q})(*)$) and an algebraic subgroup $$G\subset\text{Aut}(H^*(X,\mathbf{Q}))\times\text{GL}(\mathbf{Q}(1))$$ (automorphisms as a graded $\mathbf{Q}$-algebra) fixing the $t_1,\ldots, t_N$ and largest with respect to this property, such that $G$ also fixes $t$.

> Is $t$ algebraic?

From papers of Milne, one can deduce this is true under the variational Hodge conjecture. However, I wonder if this is already known unconditionally.

Comment: What is the relation between $t$ and $G$ (and the $t_i$)? As stated, $t$ could just be any class and $G$ the trivial group...

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I've corrected and clarified. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you are asking whether the category of homological motives generated by $X$ is tannakian, which is true if and only if homological equivalence coincides with numerical equivalence (Jannsen, Deligne). This coincidence is known for abelian varieties (Lieberman) but not much else, so I think the answer to your question is No in general.